# A Newtonian differential equation I'm having trouble with

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As an illustration to an answer over at Physics, I have been trying to work out what, for $r(0)=1$, $r'(0)=0$ and $r''(t)={{-1}\over{r(t)^2}}$, the (real) solution $r(t)$ is. Actually, I only need to figure out $r'(t)$, with $t$ such that $r(t)=0$.

It has been fun to try for a while, but now I need help. Well, I don't *need* it, but I would certainly be pleased if somebody could open my eyes.

Comment: The initial conditions make this one tough.  You'd think that $r(t) = (a+b t)^{2/3}$ would do the trick, but I can't get the condition on $r'(t)$ to work.

Comment: @rigordonma Would you say that that is conclusive? There is no analytic solution, not even to the $r"(t^*)$ question alone?

Comment: No, not at all.  This is a nonlinear equation, so unfortunately there aren't too many conclusions you can draw from my observation.  (Or at least any that I know about.)

Comment: No, I do not, because the posted "solution" violates the condition $r'(0) = 0$.  I like Marek's solution below and you should at least upvote it.

Comment: Done that, thanks. You can tell that the derivative of $y(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty[...]$ on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field) is not $0$ for $t=0$? Or is it not applicable to the ODE?

Comment: It works for the ODE in general - that's where my comment comes from.  But the solution is not any good if it does not satisfy boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$r'' = -1 / r^2,$$
$$((r')^2)' = -2 r' / r^2,$$
$$(r')^2 = 2/r + A.$$
$$r' = \sqrt{2/r + A}.$$
When $A = 0$ we have $r = (9/2)^{1/3} (t + B)^{2/3}$.

For $A \neq 0$ we need to evaluate
$$R(r) =\int {dr \over \sqrt {2/r + A}}
 = \int {rdr \over \sqrt {2r + Ar^2}},$$
which is a standard integral that I leave to you.
When you find the antiderivative put $R(r) = t + C$ and invert to obtain $r$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: @Gugg antiderivative to $f$ is a function $F$ such that $F' = f$ and is obtained by the process of integration. Does that help?

Comment: @Gugg: It's possible that it won't be doable maually. But you can still plug it into computer. In general, that's the best you can hope for.

Comment: I think $A=-2$ from the initial conditions stated.  This might help simplify things, stress on "might".

Comment: @Gugg: yes, there are methods (Mathematica, Matlab, etc.) for numerical inversion of functions. I don't expect there to be a closed-form formula (though there might be).

Comment: @Marek OK, but that is a bit too much of an investment for an aside like this. I initially thought that you had the answer already, but were just approaching this as "homework"!

Comment: @Gugg: what is your point? Are you blaming me for wasting my free time and providing you an answer with many details for absolutely nothing in return? Well, sorry about that, I won't be making this mistake again ;)

Comment: @Marek No, no, not at all! I very much appreciate your guidance. I _actually_ thought you already had the answer! But, again, I very much thank you for helping me. Friends?

Comment: @Gugg: all right, I must have misunderstood your tone. My answer was meant to be complete the way I wrote it: I solved the equation by reducing it to the integration and inversion (more elementary problems that are not related to the original question anymore). Again, this is best one can hope for except for the few simplest of equations and people usually consider the equation solved at this point. Sorry I wasn't able to provide a more satisfying answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Gugg: the ODE you've posted here is not the one for the Newtonian gravity. The potential $-1/r$ is correct only in three dimensions and then you'd need to solve _three_ equations of motion, not just one. Or you could work in polar coordinates and exploit conservation laws which reduces the problem to one equation, but again, the equation would be different from the one you've written. As for the link: neither the question nor the answers make much sense. So I am not sure what I am supposed to agree with...